# A way to pass / add addtional variables to URL in Windows Server 2008 acting as DHCP and DNS server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, redirect

We have a Windows 2008 SP2 server running as our DHCP and DNS server with IIS7 installed, every website request in the office goes through this server.

Is there a way for us to add or to pass additional variables when a user access a specific website? For example when a user visit:

https://www.officewebsite.com/commontask/index.aspx?time=1231

We would like to dynamically add a variable called "**from**" and a value of "**sales**" to it like this.

https://www.officewebsite.com/commontask/index.aspx?time=1231&from=sales

We would like to this for all query for this specific website even for like this:

http://www.officewebsite.com/ and http://officewebsite.com/login/

would be like this

http://www.officewebsite.com/?from=sales  and  http://officewebsite.com/login/?from=sales

Is this possible to do?

I'm thinking of doing this via IIS7, point the DNS to the local IIS7 and do the adding of variables there? But if I point http://officewebsite.com/ to the local IIS7 then how can the user reach the real website?

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Riverbed's 'Stingray Traffic Manager'/'SteelApp', it can definitely do what you want but it's not free.